# Draft-js get mention position in editorState currentContent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm using draft-js-mention-plugin and I'm looking for a method that returns the mention position in the whole text (without using `indexOf()`).

For exemple, I want to get the beginning and the ending positions of `piRstone` in this sentence :
`Welcome to piRstone, our new colleague.`

I'm supposed to get `11` for the beginning position and `19` for the ending.

```
<div className="editor">
    <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onEditorChange}
        plugins={plugins}
        // placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
        ref={(element) => { this.editor = element; }}
    />
    <MentionSuggestions
        onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}
        suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
        onAddMention={this.onAddMention}
    />
</div>
```

Here is my `onAddMention()` method :

```
onAddMention(object) {
    console.log(object);
}
```

Maybe there is an easier method to work with but the mentions plugin doc is a bit weak.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the offset & length of particular mention in entityRanges object of the block, the offset will be the initial index & offset + length of your mention will be the last index

```
[
  {
    "key": "4p8mh",
    "text": "Nice to meet you #name#",
    "type": "unstyled",
    "depth": 0,
    "inlineStyleRanges": [],
    "entityRanges": [
      {
        "offset": 20,
        "length": 6,
        "key": 0
      }
    ],
    "data": {}
  }
]
```

By iterating over this object you will get offset & length

```
Object.keys(content.blocks).map(i => {
         const {entityRanges, text} = content.blocks[i];
         entityRanges.map((range, idx) => {
              console.log(range.offset)
              console.log(range.length)
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 you can run these in your code to get mentions positions from editorState

```
 const rawContentState = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());
  console.log(rawContentState) <---- this is an object with a key called blocks and key called entityMap. blocks has an entityRanges object with start and end points ;))
```